# Analysing audio x seconds into the future using the Web Audio API

Tags: html5-audio, web-audio-api, audio-processing, audio-analysis

I am using an `AnalyserNode` to analyse audio provided by a `MediaElementAudioSourceNode`. Is there a way to sample and analyse the audio that will play x seconds into the future?

Comment: For just that media element?  Or for the whole stream with media elements playing at scheduled times?

Comment: Either way would be fine, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Unless you want to just slap a delay on the audio output, so you will hear the audio at the right time synced with your "future analysis".  But the media player controls, for example, will have that x-second lag.

Comment: What would be a good way to add such a delay? I was also thinking of perhaps having two media sources,  one streaming to the analyser while the other one, with an X second delay, streaming directly to the destination. Is there a way to do this with a single source, though?

Comment: It seems like the delayNode is not working for some reason: http://jsfiddle.net/vb4GM/.

Comment: Nevermind, adjusting the createDelay method maximum delay parameter worked (0 is the default value, apparently).